# listtransactions returning duplicate transactions with category "Send" & "Received" both

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client

I am facing serious problem in listtransactions call. I am getting duplicate transactions with "send" and "Received" category. For I have sent some bitcoins from 31zeoskE8zeyQARFEVzwJzsp7GQpLn5zhF to 13MwqVWaNjad4xbGV5WQPaPVcMekU5YJmB. And when I call listtransactions, I get this output,

```
    {
    "involvesWatchonly" : true,
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "3Ft9W7HfXeBMwuwcfehV9UPs5gnxbc7Wji",
    "category" : "receive",
    "amount" : 0.00019000,
    "vout" : 1,
    "confirmations" : 20,
    "blockhash" : "0000000000000000007f43360b2d7005c8f25013647359d468b8c2ef281672ab",
    "blockindex" : 438,
    "blocktime" : 1437928178,
    "txid" : "eb0f12741947a3be8fdbb15c0401a663e45bd0c68b317b58f250fbb3a698e5fa",
    "walletconflicts" : [
    ],
    "time" : 1437928101,
    "timereceived" : 1437928101
},
{
    "involvesWatchonly" : true,
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "31zeoskE8zeyQARFEVzwJzsp7GQpLn5zhF",
    "category" : "receive",
    "amount" : 0.00010000,
    "vout" : 0,
    "confirmations" : 20,
    "blockhash" : "0000000000000000007f43360b2d7005c8f25013647359d468b8c2ef281672ab",
    "blockindex" : 438,
    "blocktime" : 1437928178,
    "txid" : "eb0f12741947a3be8fdbb15c0401a663e45bd0c68b317b58f250fbb3a698e5fa",
    "walletconflicts" : [
    ],
    "time" : 1437928101,
    "timereceived" : 1437928101
},
{
    "involvesWatchonly" : true,
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "3Ft9W7HfXeBMwuwcfehV9UPs5gnxbc7Wji",
    "category" : "send",
    "amount" : -0.00019000,
    "vout" : 1,
    "fee" : -0.00010000,
    "confirmations" : 20,
    "blockhash" : "0000000000000000007f43360b2d7005c8f25013647359d468b8c2ef281672ab",
    "blockindex" : 438,
    "blocktime" : 1437928178,
    "txid" : "eb0f12741947a3be8fdbb15c0401a663e45bd0c68b317b58f250fbb3a698e5fa",
    "walletconflicts" : [
    ],
    "time" : 1437928101,
    "timereceived" : 1437928101
},
{
    "involvesWatchonly" : true,
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "31zeoskE8zeyQARFEVzwJzsp7GQpLn5zhF",
    "category" : "send",
    "amount" : -0.00010000,
    "vout" : 0,
    "fee" : -0.00010000,
    "confirmations" : 20,
    "blockhash" : "0000000000000000007f43360b2d7005c8f25013647359d468b8c2ef281672ab",
    "blockindex" : 438,
    "blocktime" : 1437928178,
    "txid" : "eb0f12741947a3be8fdbb15c0401a663e45bd0c68b317b58f250fbb3a698e5fa",
    "walletconflicts" : [
    ],
    "time" : 1437928101,
    "timereceived" : 1437928101
}
```

Why I am getting duplicate transactions in this output! ?

Any Help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: It shows up as both send and receive because you sent Bitcoins from the address to the same address. The [transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/fd473bdafd08e311f9f940afce4ebcd515e4c3ffefbb22057ead7f00cbb6f865) sends and receives to the same address.

Comment: No @NickODell, I have sent from 31zeoskE8zeyQARFEVzwJzsp7GQpLn5zhF to 13MwqVWaNjad4xbGV5WQPaPVcMekU5YJmB

Comment: And you've also sent to 31zeosk[snip]. Check the link in my last comment.

Comment: Ok that makes sense!
Now what about this, I have edited my Question, You can check another example! in my edited question @NickODell

Comment: Same thing. https://blockchain.info/tx/eb0f12741947a3be8fdbb15c0401a663e45bd0c68b317b58f250fbb3a698e5fa It withdraws from 3Ft9[snip] and deposits into 3Ft9[snip].

Comment: Yup but why "send" & "received" for 31zeoskE8zeyQARFEVzwJzsp7GQpLn5zhF ??? @NickODell

Comment: @NickODell I will be very thankful to you if you just reply to my last comment. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One is showing your send, the other is showing your receipt.  Without seeing both entries your accounting would not add up!

Answer (score 0):

Unquestionably, you will see these transactions.

if you have 10 inputs and you are about sending a transaction you should see 11 transactions.

and if you are not sending the full amount and there's some change you should see one "receive transaction" while sending and it's for change.